# Customizing recent blog posts block

Tags: theming, database, nodes

I'm including the recent blog posts block in the sidebar of my Drupal site which pulls out the 10 most recent posts in a list with the title of the post linking to the post itself. I'd like to pull out more information, specifically the "Authored by" and "Authored on" fields.

What I have at the moment:

```
<ul class="item-list">
  <li>
    <a href="#postURL#">#post title#</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

What I'd like to achieve:

```
<ul class="blog-list">
  <li>
    <a href="#postURL#">#post title#</a>
    <div class="author">#author#</div>
    <div class="date">#date</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The `blog_page_last` function in `blog.pages.inc` appears to be where the fields are being pulled out but I can't work out the additional field names (author, date) to enter.

There doesn't appear to be a `.tpl.php` file in the blog module folder and I can't find anything in `blog.module` or `blog.pages.inc` that indicates how/where the markup is set.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The block "Recent blog posts" is in blog.module.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_block_view().
 *
 * Displays the most recent 10 blog titles.
 */
function blog_block_view($delta = '') {
  global $user;

  if (user_access('access content')) {
    $result = db_select('node', 'n')
      ->fields('n', array('nid', 'title', 'created'))
      ->condition('type', 'blog')
      ->condition('status', 1)
      ->orderBy('created', 'DESC')
      ->range(0, variable_get('blog_block_count', 10))
      ->addTag('node_access')
      ->execute();

    if ($node_title_list = node_title_list($result)) {
      $block['subject'] = t('Recent blog posts');
      $block['content']['blog_list'] = $node_title_list;
      $block['content']['blog_more'] = array(
        '#theme' => 'more_link',
        '#url' => 'blog',
        '#title' => t('Read the latest blog entries.'),
      );

      return $block;
    }
  }
}
```

So there is no .tpl.php to customize. 
Using Views module to create a block which lists out recent blog posts would be a solution for you.

Hope this help,

Comment: Thanks @jiiro. I've created a view called `block--blog--recent.tpl.php` which Drupal is reading but I'm unsure how to access the data (plus the additional author and date fields) as the content is just pulled out with `<?php print $content ?>`. Is this something I need to modify in template.php?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to edit the view and add the fields that you need.

On this video it shows how to add a field, skip to 5:20 [Tutorial 2 of 10: Creating and Customizing Views](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-mQ9oj6ThGM)

Answer (score 0):

You should clone the fields template:

- In your views, find Themes, you'll see something like the image: 
  [image]
- It's the Row style output template that you should clone.
- Once the Row style output template is cloned to your theme folder, try to print out the variables $fields (with dpm() or print_r()) and you'll see your variables needed and you can customize the template here.

** You can read the comments in file views-view-field.tpl.php in the views module to see all variables available in this template.